# When rolling back a Windows driver, how do I know which version it will be?

Tags: windows, drivers

I want to roll back a driver for a device in Windows 8.1, however I'm not sure what version it will rollback to.

Is there anyway to know which specific driver will be installed without having to actually go through with the rollback process?

Example: I have audio driver 12.5 installed. I rollback, and now driver 10.0 is installed. How could I have known that 10 would be the rolled back driver?

Comment: I think it *should* roll back to whatever version of the driver you had installed previously (if you had no previous versions of the driver installed, you can't roll back).

Comment: I'm asking how to know (which) version it will roll back to...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the easiest way is to look at the "Rollback Driver Node Strong Name" entry under "Details" in the device driver. This list item only seems to exist on devices that can be rolled back.

For example, my video card has the "Roll Back Driver" button enabled. The entry for "Rollback Driver Node Strong Name" is "oem6.inf:cb0ae4149619d3c7:ati2mtag_NI:15.201.1151.0:pci\ven_1002&dev_6739" (colons seem to be the delimiters here). In this case, I know that oem*.inf drivers corresponds to a 3rd party package that I can find with pnputil in the command line. Sure enough, when I ran "pnputil -e" from the command line, it showed information about the last version of the video card driver I had installed under oem6.inf...

I suppose you could also look at keys (that correspond to the information you found above) in the registry under HKLM\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase if it turns out the rollback driver in question isn't 3rd party, and therefore won't be enumerated by pnputil.